# Create a column then add data to it with PL/SQL program

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a PL/SQL program where I add a column(called AGE_GROUP) to a table and then I insert data into this column but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    DECLARE
    cust_age string(10);
    cust_inc string(10);
    cust_status string(10);
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE DATACOPY ADD(AGE_GROUP VARCHAR2(10));';
    FOR emp IN (SELECT *
                FROM datacopy) LOOP
        cust_age := get_group_age(emp.ID);
        cust_inc := get_income_level(emp.ID);
        cust_status := fix_status(emp.ID);
      UPDATE datacopy SET AGE_GROUP = cust_age WHERE ID = emp.ID;
      UPDATE datacopy SET INCOME_LEVEL = cust_inc WHERE ID = emp.ID;
      UPDATE datacopy SET MARITAL_STATUS = cust_status WHERE ID = emp.ID;
      COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The error that I see is Error Reporting -
ORA-06550: line 12, column 27:
PL / SQL: ORA-00904: "AGE_GROUP": unacceptable identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Maxim said, at the point the PL/SQL block is parsed there is no `AGE_GROUP` column in the table, so

```
UPDATE datacopy SET AGE_GROUP = cust_age WHERE ID = emp.ID;
```

throws the ORA-00904 error you're seeing. You have to make that update statement dynamic too, e.g.:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE datacopy SET AGE_GROUP = :1 WHERE ID = :2' USING cust_age, emp.ID;
```

But your cursor query will also have a problem, because at run-time that no longer matches the table definition at compile time - so `SELECT *` now returns more columns than it expected. (The error from this is ORA-00932.)

You could make the whole cursor loop dynamic, but as you're only using the ID column you don't need to - just select that specific column instead of `*`. You should only be selecting the columns you want anyway, in all your code, of course.

So to make it work you could have:

```
DECLARE
    cust_age string(10);
    cust_inc string(10);
    cust_status string(10);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE DATACOPY ADD(AGE_GROUP VARCHAR2(10))';
    FOR emp IN (SELECT ID
                FROM datacopy) LOOP
        cust_age := get_group_age(emp.ID);
        cust_inc := get_income_level(emp.ID);
        cust_status := fix_status(emp.ID);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE datacopy SET AGE_GROUP = :cust_age WHERE ID = :id'
          USING cust_age, emp.ID;
        UPDATE datacopy SET INCOME_LEVEL = cust_inc WHERE ID = emp.ID;
        UPDATE datacopy SET MARITAL_STATUS = cust_status WHERE ID = emp.ID;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

There are a number of other issues with this code though. Using `string(10)` as a data type for your local variables isn't very Oracle-y, and they may not all actually be strings - you can use `%TYPE` for the columns that already exist on the table. You shouldn't be committing inside the loop. And you're doing three separate updates of the same row, which seems wasteful, when you could set all three column values at once - with a single dynamic statement:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE datacopy SET AGE_GROUP = :cust_age,'
  || ' INCOME_LEVEL = :cust_inc,'
  || ' MARITAL_STATUS = :cust_status'
  || ' WHERE ID = :id'
  USING cust_age, cust_inc, cust_status, emp.ID;
```

Of course, it would be simpler to just do the `ALTER` as a simple SQL statement before the PL/SQL block, rather than inside it.

It doesn't look like you really need PL/SQL at all though, or to loop over the rows one-by-one; you could do a single static update after a static alter:

```
ALTER TABLE DATACOPY ADD(AGE_GROUP VARCHAR2(10));

UPDATE datacopy SET AGE_GROUP = get_group_age(ID),
  INCOME_LEVEL = get_income_level(ID),
  MARITAL_STATUS = fix_status(ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the block is parsed first and only then executed if there are no errors. You get the parsing error because there is no age_group column in datacopy table at a parse time. You should try using dynamic SQL, ref cursor.

And remove one of the colons, it should be the following:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE DATACOPY ADD(AGE_GROUP VARCHAR2(10))';
```